# How do I assign each color of each pixel in a golang image to its own separate channel?

Tags: go, image-processing, channel

I am a go newbie, but experienced programmer.  I've spent a few hours getting acquainted and then a few days trying to figure out how to do this.  The code I offer here is cribbed from another page, but at least I got it working and can see the data.  Eventually, I want to be able to input a movie or live camera at its frame rate into these channels.  Eventually, I wish to achieve movie-in movie-out.  Ideally, each pixel color value knows its (x,y,c) indices in the image and, given an (x,y,c) the value can be peeked and poked with low overhead.  I feel like I hit a brick wall and so I ask for help.  Are there any examples of arrays of channels or conversions of arrays to channels and back again?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "image"
    "image/png"
    "os"
    "io"
    //"net/http"
)

func main() {
    // You can register another format here
    image.RegisterFormat("png", "png", png.Decode, png.DecodeConfig)

    file, err := os.Open("./test.png")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: File could not be opened")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    defer file.Close()

    pixels, err := getPixels(file)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: Image could not be decoded")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Println(pixels)
}

// Get the bi-dimensional pixel array
func getPixels(file io.Reader) ([][]Pixel, error) {
    img, _, err := image.Decode(file)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    bounds := img.Bounds()
    width, height := bounds.Max.X, bounds.Max.Y

    var pixels [][]Pixel
    for y := 0; y < height; y++ {
        var row []Pixel
        for x := 0; x < width; x++ {
            row = append(row, rgbaToPixel(img.At(x, y).RGBA()))
        }
        pixels = append(pixels, row)
    }

    return pixels, nil
}

// img.At(x, y).RGBA() returns four uint32 values; we want a Pixel
func rgbaToPixel(r uint32, g uint32, b uint32, a uint32) Pixel {
    return Pixel{int(r / 257), int(g / 257), int(b / 257), int(a / 257)}
}

// Pixel struct example
type Pixel struct {
    R int
    G int
    B int
    A int
}
```

Comment: I've read the question twice over and have to admit I'm not sure what you're asking. Can try to - very clearly - explain what you're looking for, with code samples if possible

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Suppose I have a 4 pixel camera (yes, ridiculous, but bear with me).  Each pixel generates 3 color values for each pixel in each frame, for a total of 12 (x,y,c) indexed values total.  To me, this is 12 independent channels where, for each frame, a single value is put into the channel to be processed individually by a downstream operation.  That operation should be able to query other channels by indices (x,y,c) (coordinates and color).  I hope to avoid aggregate operations such as using arrays, lists, vectors, or container of any kind.

Comment: More bluntly... A retina has 4 species of photoreceptor.  Each one has an (x,y) within the retina, and it only handles one peak wavelength.  I am trying to replicate the autonomous action of photoreceptors, except that, for camera inputs, each (x,y) has three species of cone and one species of rod photoreceptor.  Once each receptor is acting autonomously (channel) I will use that as a foundation for building more layers which sample the receptors.  This is what I am trying to do as a first go project.